# How to integrate PHP and C program?

Tags: php, c, web

Let me put my problem in a simple way. I have written a C program, which i will keep in my server. Now i am developing a
website using PHP, so that other users can also have access to my stand alone C program.

So here i want my PHP to take input from users and bring that input and run my C program and then again take the results of
the C program back to the users using PHP(probably using the same website itself).

Please suggest me how to do it. It would be easier for me to understand if you can tell me using simple program.
For example my C program has a function that adds two numbers. The users can provide their input (the numbers) using my
website. Then PHP will somehow interact with C function and return the results to the user.

Comment: Like [exec](http://se2.php.net/function.exec) — Execute an external program

Comment: Why not just write the whole site/page using either PHP or C?

Comment: note: if you do use something like `exec`, *be extremely careful* that you aren't vulnerable to shell injection attacks.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the php exec command. I'm assuming you have access to the actual C executable.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
<?php
// outputs the username that owns the running php/httpd process
// (on a system with the "whoami" executable in the path)
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a C program which parses command line arguments, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d", atoi(argv[1]) + atoi(argv[2]));
    return 0;
}
```

Then call it from PHP with exec which can put what your C program outputs to stdout into an array. See https://www.php.net/function.exec.

Answer (score 0):

Cgi-bin in Apache can execute any kind of executable on your server. PHP is typically run as an Apache module for performance purposes, but can also be run by Cgi-bin.

You could write a Cgi script (Typically in PERL) to execute your C program. You could simply write to a text-file with your C program and then accessed the same file in PHP.

Comment: And if I want to run a php in a c program?

Comment: This is kind of the opposite, but HipHop for PHP translates PHP into C++.