# Using C for calculation in PHP application: is it worth it?

Tags: php, c, performance

I have a PHP application where sometimes heavy calculations are needed (I search for operations recorded by the users and make lots of economics analysis in long periods of time).

I'd like to improve the speed of these calculations, is it worth it to rewrite these calculations parts in C? (Among the faster languages [here](http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2012/06/ruby-is-faster-than-python-php-and-perl.html), C is the one I know the most).

I had already decided doing this, but when I was looking for "how to do it" I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975532/how-to-integrate-php-and-c-program). There someone commented "*Why not just write the whole site/page using either PHP or C?*" and I know I need extra info.

Comment: only way to find out: try it both ways. doing `1+1` in a c module would be rather pointless, but calculating pi to the gazillionth place, yeah, try C.

Comment: Look at http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/07/how-to-create-php-extensions-in-c-part-i-adding-simple-function/

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Implement it in the easiest way first. If performance is unacceptable, and these calculations are the bottleneck, rewriting them in C will probably help. It shouldn't be hard, since the syntax is very similar -- you'll mostly just have to remove all the `$` characters.

Comment: It will probably only be faster if you make it a PHP extension. If you write a separate `C` program, compile it, and invoke the executable from PHP, the overhead of launching a new process will often outweigh any benefits you get.

Comment: As formulated the question is pointless because it lacks all elements for a meaningful answer (e.g. how can we rule out if it's an algorithmic problem - i.e. if you choose a O(N^2) algorithm when a O(log N) was available?). Either give more details or I'll flag the question for closing.

Comment: @CAFxX I assume the question is whether an `O( x(n) )` algorithm would benefit in being written in C for a PHP application, independent of the function `x`. But I agree it's broad.

Comment: Are the present calculations all of the same time length, or can it vary substantially? How long do they take at the moment in PHP? How quickly do you need them (could the user request them in a web app and then receive them asynchronously, for example)?

Comment: I'm wondering if you could just keep them in PHP but run them on a cron job or a Gearman worker.

Comment: I'll try out your suggestions. Namely,I can't schedule tasks, because usually users require them and wait for the outputs; also the calculs time varies a lot, it depends on the complexity of user's request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really worried about performance, **measure first** if a PHP (or other) implementation is fast enough. Possibly you will find out that there is no need to worry. If it is really heavy calculations (and there is a chance they will grow in complexity as your application evolves), it could be worth to run the calculations asynchronously in a separate backend service. For example your PHP frontend could dispatch to a C/C++ service, which eventually places results in a database. This requires lots of extra logic, somebody (the client) will have to poll regularly, but scales nicely.

There is other points to be considered than performance: if your *math* is complex and keeps growing, PHP may not be a good environment to formulate it. Then again, maybe a Java-based stack with a clear separation of frontend and business logic could be better just from a maintenance point of view.

Comment: If the maths heavy-lifting is separated to a backend service, what advantage would the OP gain by rewriting their web app in Java also?

Comment: These are independent suggestions.

Comment: Ah right, so in the Java approach, the maths stays in the web app, but is moved to a scheduler or thread?

Comment: Along that lines, yes. I'll edit it to make it clearer in a bit.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the tips. I'll mark as answered but I still have to try out your suggestions.