# Long iterative calculations in PHP/MySQL/Apache web-app: fight with timeouts

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, apache

we have a PHP/MySQL/Apache Web app which holds a rating system. From time to time we do full recalculations for ratings, which means about 500 iterations of calculation, each taking 4-6 minutes and depending on the results of previous iteration (i.e., parallel solutions are not possible). Time is taken mostly by MySQL queries and loops for each rated player (about 100000 players on each iteration, but complex logic of linking between players gives no possibility for parallelization here also).

The problem is - when we start recalculation in plain old way (one PHP POST request), it dies after about 30-40 minutes from start (which gives only 10-15 iterations completed). The question "why it dies?" and other optimization issues are kinda out of league now - too complex logic, which needs to be refactored and even maybe rewritten in other language/infrastructure, yes, but we have no resources (time/people) for it now. We just need to make things work in the least annoying way.

So, the question: what is the best way to organize such recalculation, if possible, so that site admin can start recalculation by just one click and forget about it for one day, and it still does the thing?

I found on the web few advices for similar problems, but no silver bullet:

- move iterations (and, therefore, timeouting) from server to client with usage of AJAX requests instead of plain old PHP requst - could possibly make the browser freeze (and AJAX's async nature is kinda bad for iterations);
- make PHP to start a backend service which does the thing (like advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334539/using-c-for-calculation-in-php-application-is-it-worth-it)) - it should take lot of work and I have no idea how to implement it.

So, I humbly ask for any advices possible in such situation.

Comment: You shouldn't do long tasks like this through the web interface, but use the CLI (use cron if they're on a regular schedule) or trigger such jobs as a backend process

Comment: Alas, schedule is not regular, so no cron here. And is CLI timeout-free?

Comment: By default, CLI is timeout free.... unless you explicitly set a timeout yourself